# Index out of range when it should not

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

Hello guys im learning python and im trying to make a string that concentrates binary numbers together baseed on similarity from a list .. so ['1','0','0','0','0','1','1'] becomes '1 0000 11' .. I wrote something and ive been staring at the screen for an hour trying to find the mistake i made ., anyone have any idea why is s[i]+1 giving me an out of index error when it should not be entered anyway ? .

```
s=['1','1','0','0','0','0','1']
for i in range(len(s)) :
    u=''
    if i <= (len(s)-1):
        if s[i]==s[i+1]:
            u+=s[i]
        elif s[i] != s[i+1]:
            u+=(s[i]+' ')
    elif i==len(s):
        u+=s[i]
```

Comment: What do you mean it shouldnt be? When you are on the last s, the last one, last iteration, one of your lines does s[i+1] which goes outside of the len(s)...

Comment: it should not go to last i since i specified if i<=(len(s)-1):do something with s[i+1]

Comment: elif just use s[i]

Comment: When i is 6, you check does if i<= len -1 which is 6 so you have if i (6) les than or equal to 6. meaning true. Which means you still enter that block.

Comment: Also this code doesnt really work, bc with each iteration you empty the "u" variable

Comment: thank you :D .. now i found that len() starts from 1 where index starts from 0 which makes last index not the len .. thats the mistake i was making ..  also the u part D:

Comment: Posted an answer with the corrected code

Comment: If it works accept it as an answer. Checkmark icon left side of the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
s=['1','1','0','0','0','0','1']
print("LENGTH: " + str(len(s)))
u=''
for i in range(len(s)) :
    if i < len(s) - 1:
        if s[i]==s[i+1]:
            u+=s[i]
        elif s[i] != s[i+1]:
            u+=(s[i]+' ')
    else:
        u+=s[i]
print(u)
```

IIUC, with some minor changes, this does what you want.

output: `11 0000 1`

Comment: Regarding your recent other answer, no need for shame, and thanks for deleting it.